# Fast cleaning DataSet - reading xml files (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I use a DataGrid to show a xml file. The Grid's DataSource is a DataSet.(using schema)

```
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XML_Reader.Resources.schema.xsd");
            XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(stream));
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, settings))
            {
                newDataSet.ReadXml(reader);
            }
            dataGrid.DataSource = newDataSet;
```

But when reading a new xml file, i need to clear the DataSet.(`newDataSet.Clear();`) 
Because i read 'large' (40 Mb) xml files, clearing the DataSet is very slow. 
 How can i speed up this clearing?
Reading the file is also slow !
On a: Intel i7 950, 8 Gb, Win7 64-bit.

Comment: Do you mean DataSet.Clea*r* instead of DataSet.Clea*n*?

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw: You're right !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question ;-))

A typed DataSet is simply a class you can instantiate like any other class.
There is no magic to anything generated by tools, those tools simply generate classes and you can use those classes the same way you use other classes.
Do `NewDataSet d1 = new NewDataSet();` where you put the right class name there instead of "NewDataSet".

Comment: -1: 1st of all, this answer is the exact same answer that you gave for another one of your own questions! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740486/create-new-typed-dataset-object-c/3744898#3744898  2nd, how are you addressing the speed issue with this answer?  At least make up some *new* BS!

Comment: @JohnB: The question is related. They suggest me to use a new DataSet object for each file and avoid using `DataSet.Clear();`. So the resulting question was how to create a new typed DataSet. At that point i didn't got the answer here, but wanted to share the solution. 2nd, i didn't address the speed issue (it was more a comment than a question)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just create new dataset and use that instead clearing old one? The old one will be garbage collected by .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a new `DataSet` object for each file and avoid using `DataSet.Clear()` altogether.  Just leave the old datasets to be cleared up by the garbage collector.

Comment: How can i create a new Typed DataSet ?

Comment: Where did you get `newDataSet` from in the first place?  If you newed it up and assigned the XSD yourself, just repeat the process for each file.  If you're using the design-time drag-and-drop approach, you can still achieve the same effect but it's a bit more difficult.

Comment: I added the xsd schema and used **MSDataSetGenerator** to generate the newDataSet. (VS2008).

Comment: Any help is appreciated. I can not find a solution creating a new Typed DataSet object.